# TypeError when importing a module

Tags: python, module, package, typeerror

I am new to Python and I am learning about packages. I am trying to use the random module, but I get the `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable` error. My code is:

```
import random

for i in range(3):
    print(random.random())
```

Does anyone could tell me why this might be happening?

Regards

Comment: This works perfectly for me. What python version are you using??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get a TypeError: 'module' object is not callable when trying to import the random module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672270/why-do-i-get-a-typeerror-module-object-is-not-callable-when-trying-to-import)

Answer (score 1):

What is the name of your file? If you named your file random.py, your script will not run.

[Why do I get a TypeError: 'module' object is not callable when trying to import the random module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672270/why-do-i-get-a-typeerror-module-object-is-not-callable-when-trying-to-import/2672288)

I just tested your exact same code in a test.py file and it works no problem.

Comment: I did name my file random.py . Thank you very much.

Comment: @JuanFelipeContreras no problem!